# MongoDB matching array against value in nested documents

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have searched around this problem I am facing for a bit but I haven't found a good solution without using the $lookup parameter.

My Documents currently roughly look like this:

```
{
    ...
    problems:
        [ { ... id: 1, ...}, { ... id: 7, ...}, { ... id: 122, ...} ],
    solutions:
        [ { ... assignedProblems: [1, 7] ... }, { ... assignedProblems: [122] ...} ],
    ... 
}
```

I am now trying to match the `assignedProblems` array with the `id` in `problems`.

My current aggregation looks like this:

```
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$solutions"
    },
    $lookup: {
        from: "problems",
        localField: "solutions.assignedProblems",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "problems"
    }
}
```

This aggregation works flawlessly but is painfully slow, even when using indexes.

I have tried to replace the $lookup with following:

```
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $setEquals: ["$solutions.assignedProblems", "$problems.id"]
        }
     }
```

But this does only work if the amount of problems is the same as the elements in the assignedProblems array. This is the same case when using the $eq operator.

Is there any other way to match these id's with the array?

Comment: I don't see you need `$unwind` stage. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pkuMmalepJi)

Comment: The unwind stage is not needed per se, but I am using it to look at every solution seperately. I want to exclude all `problems` that are not referenced in the `assignedProblems` array after the unwind stage

Comment: To clarify - is all of the data that you're looking to combine already on the same document (just nested in different fields) to begin with? Can you give a more complete example of input and desired output? Also, how long is `painfully slow` and how many documents are you processing?

Comment: All the data is already in the same document. `problems` and `solutions` are Arrays of documents inside a bigger document. I am currently going through 3k+ documents with an average size of 25 kB per document. Using lookup adds about 1.2 seconds to the query time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to what I was trying to do.

I replaced the `$lookup` stage to this one:

```
$addFields: {
    problems: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$problems",
            cond: {
                $in: ["$$this.id", "$solutions.assignedProblems"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This replaces the problems array with a new one that only includes the `problems` objects that have an id element that is in the `assignedProblems` array.